# Facebook OAuth redirect_uri Issue

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, oauth

I am trying to build authentication flow in our app for facebook in java. I am using facebook4j library.

My corresponding code is as follows -

```
public String authenticate() throws IOException {
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    String redirectURL = facebook.getOAuthAuthorizationURL("http://localhost:9099/default/facebook/verify.html");
    servletResponse.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    return null;
}

public String verify() throws Exception {
    String code = servletRequest.getParameter("code");
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    AccessToken accessToken = facebook.getOAuthAccessToken(code);
    String token = accessToken.getToken();
    servletResponse.getWriter().write(token);
    return null;
}
```

I am getting error after redirection on this line -

```
AccessToken accessToken = facebook.getOAuthAccessToken(code);
```

The error is as follows -

```
FacebookException{statusCode=400, errorType='OAuthException', errorMessage='redirect_uri isn't an absolute URI. Check RFC 3986.', errorCode=191, errorSubcode=-1, version=2.2.2}
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:179)
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
    at facebook4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:97)
    at facebook4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization.getOAuthAccessToken(OAuthAuthorization.java:107)
```

redirectURL that I am getting from facebook in first call is -

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=4161XXXXXX6389&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9099%2Fdefault%2Ffacebook%2Fverify.html&scope=email,public_profile,user_friends

tried without using encoding too -

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=4161XXXXXX6389&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9099/default/facebook/verify.html&scope=email,public_profile,user_friends

It is redirecting properly to 'verify' having url something like -

> [http://localhost:9099/default/facebook/verify.html?code=AQCE4aaIpE_c94J3NVNjge_YL_OP84vPIgUauvfRRXNCj_FOK8U2kfSxfKGrjWnFL1dqMeM8q22M6UaVbGsTpTQOQmjxYILdFHKFiSFd0Ycf_ByBE9rNX_yxvFnJ3RNLf7bjCT4C1uXuuqCXHZjVNN1lBb3LWUHz7eNkq0r8K14x7ZEVIWjbll-Vqys1FZuCIVDBrI4StoYkZR1rpCsoSqq7VdCIX3zawnw_nbPZBZU7iUeZJiBbahYjWkHIn47b9AQb3hZxxpe4xxXHXfDsP_h2fhC1YYioJbwGq4QbnWpUrP7aF-0Q_wF71zn4txCQLd4#*=*](http://localhost:9099/default/facebook/verify.html?code=AQCE4aaIpE_c94J3NVNjge_YL_OP84vPIgUauvfRRXNCj_FOK8U2kfSxfKGrjWnFL1dqMeM8q22M6UaVbGsTpTQOQmjxYILdFHKFiSFd0Ycf_ByBE9rNX_yxvFnJ3RNLf7bjCT4C1uXuuqCXHZjVNN1lBb3LWUHz7eNkq0r8K14x7ZEVIWjbll-Vqys1FZuCIVDBrI4StoYkZR1rpCsoSqq7VdCIX3zawnw_nbPZBZU7iUeZJiBbahYjWkHIn47b9AQb3hZxxpe4xxXHXfDsP_h2fhC1YYioJbwGq4QbnWpUrP7aF-0Q_wF71zn4txCQLd4#_=_)

facebook4j.properties

```
oauth.appId=416XXXXXXXXX389
oauth.appSecret=9ed3XXXXXXb6acXXXXXXXXc7acXXXX5
oauth.permissions=email,public_profile,user_friends
```

My Facebook App basic settings are -

[image]

The important advanced settings are -

[image]

I am totally aware that similar question has been posted earlier multiple times. I have gone through almost every question & I tried almost everything suggested to resolve this issue. But due to some reason it is not working. I decided to post my problem here after spending 3 days on the same issue.

I would highly appreciate if someone points out where exactly am I going wrong.

Comment: The `redirect_uri` parameter has to be specified when exchanging the `code` for a token as well (and has to be the same as specified earlier in the login dialog call). I’d assume that since you are using `new FacebookFactory().getInstance()` in your second method, that is not the case. Take a look at the basic implementation here, https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j-oauth-example/tree/master/src/main/java/facebook4j/examples/signin – in `SignInServlet`, the `Facebook` object instance is stored into the session, and then in `CallbackServlet` that same instance is retrieved and used again.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue exactly. I was using 2 instances of facebook4j.Facebook & second time I was not setting redirect_uri. I think it would be helpful for others, if you add your comment as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` parameter has to be specified when exchanging the code for a token as well (and has to be the same as specified earlier in the login dialog call).

I’d assume that since you are using `new FacebookFactory().getInstance()` in your second method, that is not the case. Take a look at the basic implementation here, https://github.com/roundrop/facebook4j-oauth-example/tree/master/src/main/java/facebook4j/examples/signin

In `SignInServlet`, the Facebook object instance is stored into the session, and then in `CallbackServlet` that same instance is retrieved and used again. Therefor, it still holds the `redirect_uri` value that was initially used when the Auth dialog was called, and will re-use that same value when exchanging the `code` for a token.